# Bezier curve : forcing a curve of 4 points to pass through control points in 3D space

Tags: java, math, cubic-bezier

I have read the thread to make this happen for 4 points but only in 2D space [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315432/how-to-find-control-points-for-a-beziersegment-given-start-end-and-2-intersect/2316440#) .

I have implemented the answer for 3D but only for 3 control points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711707/draw-a-quadratic-b%C3%A9zier-curve-through-three-given-points#:%7E:text=Let%20P0%2C%20P1%2C%20P2%20be%20the%20control%20points%2C,P2%2A%20%281-t%29%5E2...where%20t%20goes%20from%20zero%20to%201.)

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198446/fitting-a-single-bezier-curve-to-4-points-in-3d) post but don't understand the sudo code or the math

Can anyone simplify in java? I don't want to draw the curve as 2 segments of 3 points

Comment: What is unclear in the last link answer?

Comment: The math for the most part. The sudo code in python does little to explain it

Comment: Sorry, what does `sudo` mean?

Comment: Sorry pseudocode typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula for cubic Bezier curve component (say X):

```
X(t) = P0.X*(1-t)^3 + 3*P1.X*(1-t)^2*t + 3*P2.X*(1-t)*t^2 + P3.X*t^3
```

where `P0` and `P3` are end points, and `P1` an `P2` are control points.

We have four points for curve (`SrcPt` array in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198446/fitting-a-single-bezier-curve-to-4-points-in-3d)), end points coincide with Bezier endpoints, and two internal points on curve should define two control points `P1` an `P2` of Bezier curve. To calculate, we **must** know - what `t` parameters correspond to `SrcPt[1]` and `SrcPt[2]`. Let these parameters are 1/3 and 2/3 (possible issues are in linked answers).

So substitute `t=1/3` and `t=2/3` into the formula above:

```
SrcPt[1].X = SrcPt[0].X*(1-1/3)^3 + 3*P1.X*(1-1/3)^2*1/3 + 
             3*P2.X*(1-1/3)*1/3^2 + SrcPt[3].X*1/3^3
SrcPt[2].X = SrcPt[0].X*(1-2/3)^3 + 3*P1.X*(1-2/3)^2*2/3 + 
             3*P2.X*(1-2/3)*(2/3)^2 + SrcPt[3].X*2/3)^3
```

and solve this system for unknown `P1.X` and `P2.X`. So we will have all needed points to describe Bezier curve. Linked answer implements the solution.

Example - how changing `t` values for the same internal points influences on curve:

[image]

Comment: So that's what the determinants were about. Any reason why t was selected as 1/3 and 2/3 . Does selecting any other value effect the shape of the curve?

Comment: Determinant is part of solution of equation system. 1/3 and 2/3 are choosed arbitrarily as equal-spaced points, selecting any other values definitely effects on the curve form. You can choose another values if you have some information about positions of internal points (function in that answer allows to use another values)

Comment: That's all I needed. Thank you

Comment: Nice. And **what is the exact code** for drawing this?  I know only that  Java 7/8 has only a `path.quadTo()` method. whicah accepts  2 points (4 arguments). There's no  `path.cubeTo()` which accepts 3 points (6 arguments), as e.g. in Android Java, so that we can move to the 1st point and draw the remaining points with `path.cubeTo()`.

Comment: @Apostolos This code is intended for ready cubic Bezier primitives. Perhaps some library/framework for Java contains cubics (language itself have no graphics primitives). Of course, you can implement cubic Bezier drawing using straight line segments through Bezier subdivision, but I'd choose simpler way with a library.

Comment: Thanks., I found a reference. No need for libraries or anything. (See my answer)

Answer (score 0):

To draw the cubic curve after computing the points `p[x][y]`:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  CubicCurve2D cubcurve = new CubicCurve2D.Float(p[0][0], p[0][1], p[1][0], p[1][1], p[2][0], p[2][1], p[3][0], p[3][0]);
  g2d.draw(cubcurve);
}
```

(Re: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/CubicCurve2DFloat.htm)